# KeyError: 'bitcoin' Getting error when trying to see if crypto price went up or down

Tags: python

I'm coding in python and I'm trying to get the prices of bitcoin and ethereum currently and get the system to print me a statement of whether or not the prices went up or down or stayed the same. I'm getting an error that says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rosemary Asante\PycharmProjects\pythonProject21\main.py", line 38, in 
current_price = get_price('bitcoin')
File "C:\Users\Rosemary Asante\PycharmProjects\pythonProject21\main.py", line 34, in get_price
return Decimal(data[crypto]['usd'])
KeyError: 'bitcoin'

I'm trying to check the prices of bitcoin and ethereum. My code so far is:

```
import time
import requests
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
from decimal import Decimal





def get_price(crypto):
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={crypto}&vs_currencies=usd")
    data = response.json()
    return Decimal(data[crypto]['usd'])

previous_price = None
while True:
    current_price = get_price('bitcoin')
    if previous_price is not None:
        if current_price > previous_price:
            print("The price of Bitcoin went up.")
        elif current_price < previous_price:
            print("The price of Bitcoin went down.")
        else:
            print("The price of Bitcoin stayed the same.")
    previous_price = current_price
```

I don't know where the error is. Can someone please point out to me a solution for this?

Comment: Make sure `response.ok`.

Comment: Also based on your code, you are calling the API too many times too fast. Add some `sleep` between calls.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Maybe. My thought was that the URL https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd *does* return a JSON with `'bitcoin'` as key, so it could be a Too Many Requests problem.

Comment: I just run the code myself and the API returns `429` after a few iterations

Comment: Guys I need to check every millisecond whether or not bitcoin has went up or down how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are making requests too frequently and the API returned a `429` status code, letting you know that you are making too many requests.

You can make these changes to make it more resilient:

```py
import time
import requests
from decimal import Decimal


def get_price(crypto):
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={crypto}&vs_currencies=usd")
    if response.status_code == 200:
      data = response.json()
      return Decimal(data[crypto]['usd'])
    else:
      # Maybe log the error here?
      return None


previous_price = None
while True:
    current_price = get_price('bitcoin')
    if current_price is not None and previous_price is not None:
        if current_price > previous_price:
            print("The price of Bitcoin went up.")
        elif current_price < previous_price:
            print("The price of Bitcoin went down.")
        else:
            print("The price of Bitcoin stayed the same.")
    previous_price = current_price
    # Don't query the API too often
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: But for my program I need to check every millisecond whether or not bitcoin has went up or down. How can I do this?

Comment: You will need to use another API that allows you to do this, and I doubt you can get one for free with real time data